# CMSimple & Tinymc, adding a webcomponent or HTMLElement to the editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, web-component

I am trying to add an HTMLElment or a web-component to CMsimple or tinymc but it doesn't work, any solutions?
I have already added a button to the tinymc in der init file.
The plugin is registered but the HTMLElemnt does not work.
I have tried different ways but non of the works.

The scenario for the implementation is to use custom contents which are coming from a data base in the tinymce editor, this happens via drag and drop and the contents are pdf files and images and html contents but for now I am happy if I can insert my HTMLElement in the tinymce each time the button is clicked.
To make it easy and as an example I just use and sample HTMLElement and tried to insert it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

class ExampleComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const text = document.createElement('p');
        text.innerText = 'This is a custom component';
        
        shadow.appendChild(text);
    }
}

customElements.define('example-component', ExampleComponent);

tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table paste caas"
    ],
    toolbar: " caas | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",

});

tinymce.PluginManager.add('caas', function(editor) {
  function b() {
  tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent(tinymce.activeEditor.dom.createHTML('example-component', {id: '1'}));
  }
  editor.ui.registry.addButton("caas", { icon: "code", tooltip: "caas", onAction: b  })

});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

this is a js file which is read from the application and the button is successfully added to tinymce. What I am trying to do is to insert my element in the tinymce.
[the fiddle can be found here](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/8Qgaab/2)

the code for the real plugin which I intend to create can be found here
[the fiddle link to the real example](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/8Qgaab/4)

Comment: You are kinda asking _My car doesn't start, here is the manual_. The minimal you can add is what all those console.log statements report. Better yet, add code that we can run ( with that [ < > ] button in the SO editor)

Comment: With the  **Edit** button below your post...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, we are here to help, but not to do your job.
[Take the StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
and learn how [good questions get good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Code is what makes StackOverflow users happy, learn to include [running Code Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and you will definitly get more help.

Comment: @Ebian were you able to resolve this issue? I just opened a related question because I think the issue is, that the custom element is not defined inside the editors IFrame. Maybe you are able to answer my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75173678/4126424)